# StatET and Rmarkdowns

Tags: r, eclipse, statet

I've been struggling with this problem for a while. I am using StatET, the Eclipse plugin with R, and I would like to configure it to compile Rmarkdown documents. In order to do so, I generated a configuration setup based on the default preset (PDF Using Rmarkdown, two-steps). 
I am using StatET 3.5.1 with Eclipse NEON 4.6.0.

[image: Configuring Rmarkdown in StatET]

However, I keep getting this error. For some reason, the configuration wants to produce output files based on the variable 'file_name_base' (which should be the .Rmd file name without extension, I guess), but that is clearly empty.

```
Failed to initialize IO configuration for Produce Output.
In spec of output file, The variable 'file_name_base' references to non-existing workspace resource 'null'.
```

Do you have any idea on how I can circumvent this problem? What should I use instead of 'file_name_base' variable?

[image: StatET file name variables]

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe this is a StatET bug.

Try replacing ${file_name_base} by
    ${file_name_base:${source_file_path}}